# Exchange Online - Remove shared mailboxes from all distribution group memberships

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I've added shared mailboxes by accident to a distribution group via the Exchange Admin Center and cannot remove them because EAC doesn't specify the type of mailbox (I could accidentally remove regular mailboxes)

I've tried writing a Powershell script to complete the task but it doesn't work.

```
$DistributionGroups = Get-Distributiongroup
$SharedMailboxes = Get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails sharedmailbox
ForEach ($Group in $DistributionGroups)
{
    ForeEach ($Mailbox in $SharedMailboxes)
    {
        if ((Get-Distributiongroupmember $Group.Name | select -expand name) -contains $Mailbox)
        {
            Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$Group" -Member "$Mailbox"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies I didn't see the edit button (I thought it was like Reddit). That's been updated.

Comment: No problem, it's there for every post you make be it questions or answers, try to use it whenever you need to clarify anything rather than adding information in comments

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a syntax error on line 5 where I mispelt ForEach